# Gaussian integers relatively prime to $9$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, gaussian-integers

I wish to count all Gaussian integers (modulo $9$) that are relatively prime to $9$.
So far, I can easily do this for any Gaussian prime, by drawing the fundamental parallelogram and identifying all residues within. However, I am not certain how to do this for a non-prime, namely $9$. I have observed that $9 = 3\times 3$, where $3$ is a Gaussian prime, but am not sure how to use this information to obtain the Gaussian integers that are relatively prime to $9$.

I do not need to identify these integers, only to count them.

Edit: I believe that the correct answer can be computed by counting the number of residues in the fundamental parallelogram ($81$) and subtracting the number of residues that are not coprime to $9$ (i.e., which have $3$ as a common factor, or, since $3$ is prime, which are *multiples* of 3.). Now, does the problem reduce to counting the possible multiples of $3$ in the fundamental parallelogram? I think I can count these by translations of a parallelogram of sidelength 3.

Comment: relatively prime to 9 is the same as relatively prime to 3

Comment: @Ihf Apparently, $\Phi(p^k) = N(p)^{k-1} \Phi(p)$, where $\Phi$ represents the Euler totient function. If, in the Gaussian integers, relatively prime to 9 should be the same as relatively prime to 3, then $\Phi(3) = \Phi(9)$, which is not so?

Comment: @Ihf https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3811400/euler-totient-function-for-gaussian-integers ... I don't think this property holds in the Gaussian integers.

Comment: May be this is your first time using internet. Let me tell you that writing in ALLCAPS is the equivalent of yelling. Please, don't yell at us.

Comment: @jjagmath I meant only to emphasise an important correction, my apologies.

Comment: As $3$ is prime in the Gaussians, $9$ factors only as $3^2$, so @lhf is correct in saying relatively prime to $9$ is relatively prime to $3$. This does not mean $\phi(9)=\phi(3)$ – it doesn't mean that in the integers, why should it mean that in the Gaussians? Anyway, a full set of Gaussian residues modulo $9$ is given by $\{a+bi:0\le a\le8,0\le b\le8\}$, and the ones that are not relatively prime to $9$ (equivalently, not relatively prime to $3$) are the ones of the form $3r+3si$.

Comment: So, V.E, can you solve the problem now?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, I can solve the problem now, thank you very much.

Comment: Good. Let me encourage you to write up your answer, and post it as an answer to this question.