# Euler Phi Function for Gaussian integers

Tags: number-theory, totient-function, gaussian-integers

I am considering the Euler totient function for Gaussian integers. In reference to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3811400/euler-totient-function-for-gaussian-integers) question, I would wish to use the fact that
$\phi(p^{k})=N(p)^{k−1}\phi(p)$ if $p$ is prime, but have not succeeded in finding a proof anywhere.

Alternatively, a more specific formula is given [here](https://eoinmackall.wordpress.com/2018/10/22/the-euler-phi-function-for-the-gaussian-integers/) by $\phi(p^{k})=N(z)^k - N(z)^{k-1}$ if $N(z) \equiv_{4} 1$, but I also do not know how to rigorously show this.

Comment: Do you know how to prove this for integer primes?

Comment: It might help if you were to tell us what you mean by $N$, V. Elizabeth.

Comment: If you have access to a library that gets the American Mathematical Monthly, you could have a look at The Euler φ-Function in the Gaussian Integers, James T. Cross, The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 90, No. 8 (Oct., 1983), pp. 518-528 (11 pages)

Comment: Making any progress, V.E?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have found an alternative solution to my problem, which does not require the use of either identity.